# How to avoid Excel freezing while VBA script is waiting on return of WScript.Shell?

Tags: python, excel, vba

My VBA code will run a Python script and wait for its result to proceed with other calculations. To be more exact, the python script generates a CSV file and then VBA retrieves data in that CSV file. Sample codes to call the python script:

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdString = "cmd.exe /C ""C:\Anaconda3\python.exe ..... " 'to run a Python script
wsh.Run cmdString, 1, True
Set wsh = Nothing
```

The problem is while the python script is running (takes ~ 5 minutes to finish), I can't edit cells in other workbooks in the meantime. I understand it is normal behaviour and a common solution is use DoEvents which is not applicable in this situation. Two solutions that I can think of are:

1. Call the script without waiting on return, and then manually start remaining VBA script i.e. by pressing a button
2. Schedule Application.OnTime event, for example, 5 minutes later to check if the file is created by the python script. Repeat until it is created and proceed remaining VBA script automatically

I prefer approach 2 over approach 1 since it runs automatically. But before implementing it, I would like to know if there is any better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Since VBA has no multi-threading support there is only these 2 ways. Wait for a response or repeatedly check if your script has produced the desired files. Waiting for response without stopping VBA in this step until the script finished is not possible.

Comment: As you mentioned, that is normal behaviour as excel is a single thread application (which at times can be limiting but we have to remember that excel is not meant to be a **full** development platform). Saying that, i would make further suggestions to your **option 2** and say, let python trigger a different excel file which completes the remaining task. That way you are free to do what you need

Comment: appreciate the quick replies! @Zac, I hadn't thought of that. I have just added codes in the python script to run a VBA macro subsequently, and it works like a charm. Thanks so much.